# Conditionally move tab separated values

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have input from a tab-separated text file

```
25/08/2013  B   TRUE
25/08/2013  L   FALSE
25/08/2013  D   TRUE
26/08/2013  L   FALSE
26/08/2013  D   TRUE
27/08/2013  B   TRUE
27/08/2013  L   TRUE
27/08/2013  D   TRUE
28/08/2013  B   FALSE
28/08/2013  D   FALSE
29/08/2013  B   FALSE
```

The first column is the date. The second one is Breakfast, lunch, or dinner.
As you can see, some data is missing: breakfast on the 26th and lunch on the 28th.

Now I would like to bring this data into an excel spreadsheet like this:

[image]

Where the data missing yields an empty field and the rest is transferred.

I hope this is possible and easy.
Thanks!

Comment: It is possible, but not easy. Start with Text Import Wizard to import the text (the easy part). Afterwards, some formatting operations (or filtering options) might be used (the hard part).

Comment: yes, I had gotten as far as importing the text into excel with the wizard. I am now stuck at the second part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have your tab-delimited data imported into Excel, you can build your table using formulas.

1. Create the headers for your table. Then, in the first cell under Date (`E3` in my example), enter the formula

   ```
   =MIN($A$3:$A$15)
   ```

   where `A3:A15` is the column of dates in the original data.
2. In the cell below that (`E4` in my example), enter the formula

   ```
   =E3+1
   ```

   and fill down as far as you like.
3. In the first cell in the Breakfast column, enter the formula

   ```
   =IFERROR(CHOOSE(SUMPRODUCT(1*($E3=$A$3:$A$15),1*($B$3:$B$15=LEFT(F$2,1)),($C$3:$C$15)*2+1*NOT($C$3:$C$15)),FALSE,TRUE),"")
   ```

   where the column header is in `F2`, the BLD column of the original data is in `B3:B15`, and the TF column of the original data is in `C3:C15`.
4. Fill this formula down the column. Then fill the formula to the right through all the columns. Note that the `LEFT(F$2,1)` bit just plucks the first letter off the column header to check the BLD values against. If your actual data doesn't follow this pattern, you can replace this part of the formula with the value you want to match wrapped in quotes (e.g., `"B"` instead).

[image]

Comment: great, this worked! I had to spend about 10 minuted tinkering with it, until I realized that my excel wants semicolons instead of commas. With semicolons, it works. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

I’ll assume that you have imported your input data to Columns R through T:

[image]

Like [Excellll](https://superuser.com/users/76571/excellll), I converted the dates to m/d/yyyy format so they would work on my system. 
Now, to put the results that you want into Columns A through D:

1. Create a helper column Q by entering `=R2&S2` into cell `Q2` (or by entering `=R1&S1` into cell `Q1`, if you don’t have a header row) and dragging/filling down:

   [image]
2. Fill Column A with the dates you want. There are many ways to do this:

   1. To get complete coverage for a range,

      - Set cell `A2` to `=MIN(R2:R12)` (or `=MIN(R1:R12)`, if you don’t have a header row in Column R), or simply enter the start date you want, and then
      - Set cell `A3` to `=A2+1` and drag/fill cell `A3` down.  Or just drag/fill cell `A2` down.  Or drag/fill cell `A2` down *with the right mouse button* and choose between “Fill Days” and “Fill Weekdays”.

      OR
   2. Use the dates that are present in your data, and no others.

      - Make sure that Column R has a header, and then
      - Select the column (the header and all the data), and then
      - Go to the “Data” tab, “Sort & Filter” panel, and click “Advanced”, and then
      - Select “Copy to another location”, enter `A:A` for “Copy to”,
        select “Unique records only” (and click “OK”).
3. Enter `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2&LEFT(B$1,1), $Q$1:$T$12, 4, FALSE), "")` into cell `B2`,
   and drag down and to the right as in Excellll’s answer. 
   His comment about `LEFT(F$2,1)` applies equally to my `LEFT(B$1,1)`.

[As you have discovered, some localizations of Excel require
that function arguments be separated by semicolons.]

If you want to make this transformation permanent, and delete your original data,
just copy and then paste values.

I submit that this answer is simpler than the others that have been presented. 
Also, mine is more flexible, as (I believe) the other fail
if any data other than `TRUE` or `FALSE` is entered into your rightmost column,
while mine can handle things like `eggs`, `sandwich`, and `salad`,
prices paid, time of day, location, or whatever.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I hope I did not go against etiquette by marking Excell's as the answer before waiting for more answers.

Comment: @tomtim: If Super User has etiquette rules that cover that, I don’t know them.  And it’s not my place to tell you what to do.  But (1) I believe that you can un-accept an answer and accept a new one: see the [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://superuser.com/help/someone-answers) page of the [Asking](http://superuser.com/help/asking) section of the [Help Center](http://superuser.com/help).  (But only one answer can be accepted.)  And (2) you should be able to up-vote any number of answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it pretty quickly with a helper column, a pivot table, and a custom format in the pivot table.  See below.

Import your data to excel and use the "text-to-columns" menu to split it as shown in columns A:C.

The helper column D assigns a 1 for TRUE and 0 for FALSE for the values in column C.

Build the pivot table as shown using the helper column in the VALUES section.  You'll initially have the 1's and 0's showing up in the VALUES section.

Then in the "Value Field Settings" you can convert the 1's and 0's back to TRUE and FALSE with the Custom number format "True"; "True"; "False".
[image]